# Canvas coords overflow?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How to prevent some canvas coords overflowing?

Example case:

The following javascript:

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.width = 500;
 canvas.height = 500;
 context.strokeStyle = "#000";
 context.beginPath();
 // line from (100, 100) to (100,999999999999.9)
 context.moveTo(100.0, 100.0);
 context.lineTo(100.0, 999999999999.9); 
 // line from (200, 200) to (200,9999999999999.9)
 context.moveTo(200.0, 100.0);
 context.lineTo(200.0, 9999999999999.9);
 context.stroke();
```

gives this canvas output

[image: Output]

In these examplex both lines have the end Y-coord positive but the second one seems to be interpreted like `-Inf`. It seems that internally the values are cast to some `unsigned int` making some bit value considered like the sign but I found no explicit documentation about it.

## UPDATE

What I want is to draw the line correctly not to prevent drawing lines with coords out of canvas image.
I know there is a way doing some linear algebra (calculating the intersection point between the line and the border) but I want to know if there is some simpler method.

Comment: You might wanna consider whether it's not design flaw that you get these results. I added you an answer but you must understand that checking for valid coordinates will cost you some performance.

Comment: It seems a good advice. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [tl;dr Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/c79fyymd/1/)

The data type of `moveTo` and `lineTo` paramteters is [`unrestricted double`](http://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL/#idl-unrestricted-double). You can see that it's 32bit floating point number, presumably signed. That means that by *specification*, there should be no overflow and the error depends on your browser's implementation.

My tests confirmed this, because neither Firefox, Google Chrome or Opera did render anything at all, indicating undefined suspicious behavior. If the coordinate is invalid, I'd expect an error. If I used smaller coordinates (300), they all provided this result (cropped, framed):

[image: image description]

I then performed some tests and the last number that can be rendered is:

```
Math.pow(2,31)-Math.pow(2,6)-1 = 2147483583
```

So if you're actually trying to solve a problem and not asking out of curiosity, I propose one of these two solutions:

1. **Make a helper function to cap the coordinates.**

   ```
     var max = 2147483583;
     var min = -2147483583;
     function safeCoordinate(number) {
       if(number>max)
         return max;
       if(number<min)
         return min;
       return number;
     }
   ```

   Then just call:

   ```
   context.lineTo(safeCoordinate(x), safeCoordinate(y));
   ```
2. **Override actual canvas methods to fix the issue**

   If you're feeling tough, you can actually go ahead and override canvas context methods. That's something many people would advise you against though, as changing built in stuff often causes mysterious errors that are hard to track down. With this warning out of the way:

   ```
   (function(max, min, context_proto) {
             // Override move to
             var old_moveTo =context_proto.moveTo;
             context_proto.moveTo = function(x, y) {
                 return old_moveTo.call(this, safeCoordinate(x), safeCoordinate(y));   
             }
             var old_lineTo =context_proto.lineTo;
             context_proto.lineTo = function(x, y) {
                 return old_lineTo.call(this, safeCoordinate(x), safeCoordinate(y));   
             }
             // Override more methods if needed!
               ...
             // Our helper function
             function safeCoordinate(number) {
               if(number>max)
                 return max;
               if(number<min)
                 return min;
               return number;
             }  
   })(2147483583,-2147483583, CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype);
   ```

Comment: Thanks. It should works according to standard, but is a implementation issue. Other non-browser canvas engines (android) have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a `canvas.height = 500` and `canvas.width = 500` and we want to prevent the coords to be within the range `0 to 500`. We can use those properties to set a range when the context is called using a `function()`.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;
context.strokeStyle = "#000";
letsDraw(100, 200, 800, 300); //Returns Alert Error


function letsDraw(moveToX, moveToY, lineToX, lineToY){
     if((moveToX<canvas.width && moveToX>0) && (moveToY<canvas.height && moveToY>0)){
       context.beginPath();
       context.moveTo(moveToX, moveToY);
       if((lineToX<canvas.width && lineToX>0) && (lineToY<canvas.height && lineToY>0)){
         context.lineTo(lineToX, lineToY);
         context.stroke();
       } else {
         alert("Range outside Canvas");
         return false;
       }
     } else {
       alert("Range outside Canvas");
       return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: He's not asking about canvas element range I suppose.

Comment: That is not  what I want. I think is my mistake because can be misunderstood. What I want is to draw the line but preventing these unwanted -Inf behavior.

I made an update of the question.